# Loop over two arrays in Twig

Tags: arrays, loops, twig

I have no idea how you call the following, but I need a sort of pattern within my loop.

Let's assume I have 2 arrays.

```
Array1 = 1..10

Array2 = ['a','b','a','b','b']
```

The outcome I need should be:

```
1a,
2b,
3a,
4b,
5b,
6a,
7b,
8a,
9b,
10b
```

How do I achieve this with a Twig template?

Comment: Also, please clarify if the size of one array is guaranteed to be a multiple of the size of the other.

Comment: Hey, did you solve your problem?

Comment: Hello Droid, yes today I've learned that twig has a function called cycle.
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/cycle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `modulo` in `JavaScript`:

```js
const _getArr = (from, to, chars) => {
  const res = [];
  const len = chars.length;
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
    console.log(count, count%len, chars[count % len]);
    res[count] = `${i}${chars[count % len]}`;
    count++;
  }
  return res;
}

console.log( _getArr(1, 10, ['a','b','a','b','b']) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using *modulo* arithmetics, e.g. (**C#** [code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NEw4eO)):

```
// result array will be max of Array1 and Array2 lengths  
string[] Array3 = new string[Math.Max(Array1.Length, Array2.Length)]; 

// Note Array1[i % Array1.Length] and Array2[i % Array2.Length] 
// index of each array (Array1, Array2) is remainder of Array1.Length or Array2.Length
// So i % Array1.Length will be 0, 1, ..., Array1.Length, 0, 1, 2 etc 
for (int i = 0; i < Array3.Length; ++i)
  Array3[i] = $"{Array1[i % Array1.Length]}{Array2[i % Array2.Length]}";

// Let's have a look at Array3:
Console.Write(string.Join(", ", Array3));
```